# Android HttpClient hangs simultaneous requests until I execute request to another host

Tags: java, android, httpclient

I have a problem using DefaultHttpClient.

If I execute some requests simultaneously to the same server (> 2) it will hang them (no responses will be received). All next requests will hang too.

Here is the code.

```
public class ConnectionService {

    // Should be called once with application context
    public static void initWithContext(Context ctx) {
        // Creating custom multithread connection manager to handle multiple simultaneous requests
        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
        schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
        ClientConnectionManager cm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, schemeRegistry);
        ConnManagerParams.setMaxTotalConnections(params, 200);
        ConnPerRoute cpr = new ConnPerRoute() {
            @Override
            public int getMaxForRoute(HttpRoute httpRoute) {
                return 50;
            }
        };
        ConnManagerParams.setMaxConnectionsPerRoute(params, cpr);

        httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(cm, params);
        httpClient.setCookieStore(new PersistentCookieStore(ctx));
    }

    static private DefaultHttpClient httpClient = null;

    private JsonExecutorInterface requestExecutorForRelativePathAndParams(String path, WebParams params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(rootUrl.toString() + path);

        if(params != null) {
            postRequest.setEntity(params.getFormEntity());
        }

        JsonExecutorProxy executor = new JsonExecutorProxy();
        executor.setRequest(postRequest);
        executor.setErrorsHandlerDelegate(this);

        return executor;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely due to how you are constructing the `ThreadSafeClientConnManager` you are using. If you change the order slightly you should get a better result.

```
    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
    // The params are read in the ctor of the pool constructed by
    // ThreadSafeClientConnManager, and need to be set before constructing it.
    ConnManagerParams.setMaxTotalConnections(params, 200);
    ConnPerRoute cpr = new ConnPerRoute() {
        @Override
        public int getMaxForRoute(HttpRoute httpRoute) {
            return 50;
        }
    };
    ConnManagerParams.setMaxConnectionsPerRoute(params, cpr);
    SchemeRegistry schemeRegistry = new SchemeRegistry();
    schemeRegistry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
    ClientConnectionManager cm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, schemeRegistry);
```