# Loading HTTPS images in Android using Volley

Tags: java, android, https, httpclient

I have been using Volley as my solution to download, cache, and display images on Android with the NetworkImageView.

So far, everything this has worked quite well. However, on this particular project I need to retrieve images behind HTTPS. I have researched and tried to do this on my own for a few days but the information I have come upon has been quite confusing and I am in dire need of clarification.

I have been using the following thread to try and implement this. [Volley NetworkImageView using https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23133465/volley-networkimageview-using-https)

However the answer there isn't well explained and I don't quite understand the concept at play.

I am looking for is an explanation of **What** I need to extra to load images from behind HTTPs using Volley and **Why**.

Comment: What specific problems are you encountering? For the vast majority of HTTPS sites, it should just work.

Comment: The image url I try simply doesn't load anytime I try it. However the url will load on my browser fine. Which leads me to believe there is some SSL stuff I have to handle. This is the url in question [link](https://www.cub.com/content/dam/B2C/enterprisebannerwebsites/Cub/CUB_WK25_HP_BackToSchool.jpg)

Comment: Unless Volley is doing something strange, it should handle conventional SSL sites without issue. You need to do extra stuff if the HTTPS request is from a server with a self-signed certificate, or uses a root CA that is unknown. Your server has a Verisign root certificate, which should be just fine.

Comment: Lets say i had to create an HTTP Stack to use how do I do that with Volley.